# How to play a particular item in playlist jwplayer

Tags: jwplayer, playlist

I have a list of mp3 audio files. Suppose i have 10 audio files in playlist then i have 10 buttons to play the playlist item. On first button click 1 audio in playlist will play and so on. I don't want to make separate player for all the 10 audios as then i can play it just using the id of player and play event.

Please anyone have any ideas.

Thanks,

Comment: Why not just use one player with one playlist? - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29249/playlist-sidebar-component

Comment: ya i have seen this before. but my situation is different. i have to make dynamic playing a loop is ther for all audio. I am trying to do it.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you are doing?

Comment: I have an array of mp3 files. Now i have to make a loop for that array and make a playlist. I am not showing the playlist to user. User will just see buttons with some text. Now user will click on button and hear the sound. User can click on any on the buttons and respective audio should play. My question is: Is it possible to capture the playlist item on a button click which is not part of playlist. just using some Ids.

Comment: Yes, possibly using our API - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference

Comment: Thanks Can we also define a custom index on playlist item

Comment: Yes, getPlaylistItem(index)
    Returns the playlist item object at the specified index. If the index is not specified, the currently playing playlistItem is returned.

Comment: Its ok but my question is suppose i have an array of 10 elements where i have 7 elements with audios and 3 dont have then if i make a playlist then it will have only 7 playitems with index 0 to 6. But now what if some of my audios are not in 0 to 6 index in array. Then how will I map the audio array index with playlist item index. Hope you understand it.

Comment: As i just hidden the playlist and player and just using 7 buttons to play the particular playitem. 7 is just a number. it can be more as long as i have audio data in array.

Comment: Do you mean you want to only strip out the audio items from the playlist itself?

Comment: No i just want to define a custom index on every playlist item so that i can map that index with some other index.

Comment: Sorry, I a not really sure what you are trying to do?

Comment: my question is very simple. I just want to put custom indexing on each playlist item so that i can use it like this getPlaylistItem(index) where index is my custom index. but i dont think there is a way to put your custom indexing while making playlist.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I do not believe that is possible, unfortunately.